# What's the meaning of `@anaconda` of `yum list`?

Tags: centos, yum

I use `yum list`:

[image]

there shows the `@anaconda` and `redhat_cdrom`.

I want to know what's the meaning of `@anaconda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@anaconda` mean all listed(installed) package is coming from anaconda installer programme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(installer). `redhat_cdrom` is your repo name.